# compare strings in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I wrote a function that takes two strings as arguments and compares them and returns bool value. Here is the code.

```
function compareStringsbyBytes(string s1, string s2) public pure returns(bool)
{
bytes memory s1bytes = bytes(s1);
bytes memory s2bytes = bytes(s2);
if(s1bytes.length!=s2bytes.length) {
    return false;
}
else{
    for(uint i = 0;i<s1bytes.length;i++)
    {
        if(s1bytes[i] != s2bytes[i])
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

The contract deployment failed in this case with transaction out of gas error. Can someone help me understand the problem with this code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe it's easier to compare the hashes of both strings: `return keccak256(s1) == keccak256(s2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@henkiedoodle's comment is correct, it would be much simpler and easier to compare hashes of the strings.

You are unable to directly compare strings, (ie `return(s1 == s1)` will give the error 
`TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory`), but if the strings are identical then so will their hashes be.

The full function could then be simplified to

```
function compareStringsbyBytes(string s1, string s2) public pure returns(bool){
    return keccak256(s1) == keccak256(s2);
}
```

However, in future if you receive the out of gas error, you may also want to try increasing the gas limit of your transaction.

Update: the above answer (and the question) were both circa Solidity 0.4.X. For 0.5.X, the following would be a valid compare function

```
function compareStringsbyBytes(string memory s1, string memory s2) public pure returns(bool){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the contract deployment fails, you should be looking for other issues:

1. The contract does not compile under your version of `solc` (depends on tools used), meaning you are trying to deploy an empty bytecode.
2. Something in the constructor does not work, e.g. a `require()` condition is not met.
3. The deployment cost is beyond your *unlocked* account's balance or it is over the amount of gas supplied (you may have to increase if the estimate is incorrect), or it is over the chain's block `gasLimit`.

It's unlikely the failure to deploy the contract has anything to do with the design of this function since it is not involved in deployment itself. As an aside, I would upvote the hash comparison idea on grounds of readability and simplicity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The hash comparision idea worked. But i still cannot figure out the reason forfailure in my case. It don't give any errors with code, but contract cannot be deployed :(:(

Comment: The problem is not in the piece of code in your question.

Comment: You are true. there is not problem with the piece of code, it is working fine. the problem is with the contract size. it has many dynamic arrays and I am running out of gas because of that